# Is there any possible to convert Edittext what ever the enterd text only into image in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

[  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lnz0U.png!][1]I have written code for converting edittext to image but i want only text what ever i entered in edittext only that text convert into image(not over all edittext). please help me

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "barbatrick.ttf");
    et.setTypeface(font);
    et.setCursorVisible(false);
    et.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(et.getDrawingCache());
    ImageView iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are doing but if you want to convert text into image, then yes it's possible, but it's too complicated AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

```
public Bitmap getViewImage(View view) {
    view.buildDrawingCache();
    return view.getDrawingCache();
}
```